# Scatterplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a scatterplot of count vs. depth of 12 species using ggplot.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = ReefFish, mapping = aes(count, depth))
```

However, how do I use geom_point(), geom_smooth(), and facet_wrap() to include a smoother as well as include just the 12 species I want from the data (ReefFish)? Since I believe what I have right now includes all species from the data.

Here is an example of part of my data:

[image]

Comment: `filter()` your data frame to include only the 12 species you want before calling `ggplot()`.  As for how to use `geom_xxxx()`, that's impossible to say without sight of your data.

Comment: `Error in ggplot(data = ReefFish, mapping = aes(count, depth)) : object 'ReefFish' not found`. Where can we find this data set?

Comment: It is a huge dataset, what is the best way for me to share it for you? I edited the question and included an example of a piece of the data.

Comment: How do I include all 12 species in the filter() function? Would it be something like:

    filter("species 1" "species 2" etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have access to the `ReefFish` data set, here's an example using the built-in `mpg` data set about cars. To make it work with your data set, just edit this code to replace manufacturers with species.

### Filter the data

First we filter the data so that it only includes the species/manufacturers we're interested in.

```
# load our packages
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

# set up a character vector of the manufacturers we're interested in
manufacturers <- c("audi", "nissan", "toyota")

# filter our data set to only include the manufacturers we care about
mpg_filtered <- mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer %in% manufacturers)
```

### Plot the data

Now we plot. Your code was just about there! You just needed to add the plot elements, you wanted, like so:

```
mpg_filtered %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = cty, 
                       y = hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~manufacturer)
```

Hope that helps, and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: This is very helpful! However, I'm a little confused on the mpg_filtered part.

This is what I have so far:

Comment: species <- c("Vanderbilt's chromis", "Agile chromis", "Brown surgeonfish", "Spotted surgeonfish", "Yellow tang", "Common bluestripe snapper", "Arc-eye hawkfish", "Hawaiian bicolor chromis", "Whitebar surgeonfish", "Saddle wrasse", "Striated wrasse", "Pebbled butterflyfish")

mpg_filtered <- mpg %>%
  filter(species %in% ReefFish)

mpg_filtered %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(count, depth)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~species)

Comment: In "manufacturer %in% manufacturers", is "manufacturers" the dataset?

Comment: Or is "mpg" the dataset?

Comment: Hi Alison, my bad for skipping a few steps. Is your data public? It's hard to give answers without it, but I assume there is a column in ReefFish with the species names, and I'll call it `SPECIES`. So here `species` is the vector we set up of interesting fish, and `SPECIES` (all caps) is the name of the column in `ReefFish`. You'll need to edit the code to reflect the actual column name.

Then you could try: `fish_filtered <- ReefFish %>% filter(SPECIES %in% species)`, and then `fish_filtered %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(count, depth)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth() + facet_wrap(~SPECIES)`

Comment: Also, try running the code I provided in the answer a few times and playing around with it. `mpg` is a data set included in the package **ggplot2** so it should run on your computer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I've almost got it. I played around with it but I am getting this error:

Error in ReefFish %>% filter(commonname %in% species) : 
  could not find function "%>%"

I don't understand why that wouldn't be found.

Comment: Great! `library(magrittr)` will load the pipe operator `%>%`, but you can also just use `library(tidyverse)` to load a lot of the functions we're using here all at once.

Comment: That worked!! However, now on the last chunk of code I'm getting this error:

Error: Faceting variables must have at least one value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237130/discussion-between-christopher-belanger-and-alison-meeth).